# How to find all solutions to system of congruences with Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

Here is my work so far

gcd(3, 4) = 1 $\,$gcd(3, 5) = 1$\,$gcd(4,5) = 1

$\quad$ mod 3 $\quad$ mod 4 $\quad$mod 5 
x $\equiv$ 4 * 5$\qquad$3 * 5 * 3 $\quad$ 3 * 4 * 4
Applying mod 3 to everything, you get  x $\equiv$ 20$\equiv$2 (mod 3), which matches up 
Applying mod 4 to everything, you get x $\equiv$ 15$\equiv$3 (mod 4), which doesn't match up with 
x $\equiv$2 (mod 3) so i multiplied 15 by 3 to get 45, meaning x $\equiv$ 45$\equiv$1 (mod 4)
And finally after applying mod 5 to everything, you get x $\equiv$ 12$\equiv$2 (mod 5), which doesn't match up with x $\equiv$3 (mod 5) so I multiplied 12 by 4 to get 48, meaning x $\equiv$ 48$\equiv$3 (mod 5).
To find one solution, I added up (4)(5) + (3)(5)(3) + (3)(4)(4) to get 113. I tested this solution and it worked for the system of congruences. 
How would you find all the other solutions to this? Would you use set builder notation?

Answer (score 1):

Set-builder notation is just a compact way of describing a set. You can use set-builder notation to **describe** the set of solutions once you find out what that set is, but it won’t help you actually to find the solutions.

Proceed as in the video: $3\cdot4\cdot5=60$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $3,4$ and $5$, so adding or subtracting any integral multiple of $60$ won’t affect the value modulo $3,4$, or $5$. That is $60\equiv 0\pmod 3$, so $113+60n\equiv 2+0\cdot n\equiv 2\pmod 3$, so any number of the form $113+60n$ is still a solution to the first congruence. Similar calculations show that $113+60n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $113+60n\equiv 3\pmod 5$ for each integer $n$, so every number of the form $113+60n$ is a solution to the system of three congruences. It turns out that these are the only solutions, so the set of solutions is

$$\{113+60n:n\in\Bbb Z\}\;,$$

where as usual $\Bbb Z$ is the set of integers. Equivalently, it’s

$$\{n\in\Bbb Z:n\equiv 113\!\!\pmod{60}\}\;.$$

Note that in most contexts it’s customary to take $53$, obtained when $n=-1$, as a more or less standard representative of this set rather than $113$, so that one would more likely write

$$\{n\in\Bbb Z:n\equiv 53\!\!\pmod{60}\}\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is much easier to successively solve the system in pairs. For example:

${\rm mod}\ 5\!:\  3\equiv x\iff x = \color{#0a0}{3+5i}$

$\smash[t]{{\rm mod}\ 4\!:\  1\equiv x\equiv \color{#0a0}{3\!+\!5i}\equiv 3\!+\!i\iff i = -2\!+\!4j\iff x=\color{#0a0}{3\!+\!5}(\overbrace{-2\!+\!4j}^{\large\color{#0a0} i})=\,\color{#c00}{-7\!+\!20j}}$

$\smash[b]{{\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ 2\equiv x\equiv \color{#c00}{-7+20j}\equiv 2-j\iff j\equiv0\iff j=3k\iff x= \,\color{#c00}{-7+20}\underbrace{(3k)}_{\large\color{#c00}j}}$

Thus $\,x\,$ satisfies the system $\iff x\equiv \color{#c00}{-7}\equiv 53\pmod{60}$

Answer (score 0):

The system of equations is

$$\begin{cases}x=\color{green}2\pmod 3\\
x=\color{green}1\pmod4\\
x=\color{green}3\pmod5\end{cases}$$

Now do as the proof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Chinese_Remainder_Theorem) :

$$\begin{align}&N_1=20\implies x_1=N_1^{-1}\pmod3=\color{red}2\\
&N_2=15\implies x_2=N_2^{-1}\pmod4=\color{red}3\\
&N_3=12\implies x_3=N_3^{-1}\pmod5=\color{red}3\end{align}$$

and now we define

$$x:=20\cdot\color{green}2\cdot\color{red}2+15\cdot\color{green}1\cdot\color{red}3+12\cdot\color{green}3\cdot\color{red}3=233=53\pmod{3\cdot4\cdot5}=53\pmod{60}$$